# struct's string field as function's parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-parameter

I have a struct

```
typedef struct HASH_NODE
{
    char*              word;
    struct HASH_NODE*  next;
} HASH_NODE;
```

and function

```
void foo(char* destptr, const char* srcptr)
{
    destptr = malloc(strlen(srcptr)+1);
    strcpy(destptr, srcptr);
}
```

I want to pass structs field .word to foo and I expect that value of my field would be changed after function return, but it doesn't:

```
int main (void)
{
    HASH_NODE* nodeptr = malloc(sizeof(HASH_NODE));
    nodeptr->next = NULL;
    nodeptr->word = NULL;
    char* word = "cat";
    foo(nodeptr->word, word);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Or you could return a pointer from foo. and assign to             `nodeptr->word = foo(const char* srcptr)` but I think this is not your intention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the pointer `destptr` passed to `foo()` by malloc'ing. Pass a pointer to pointer from `main()` to `foo()`:

```
void foo(char** destptr, const char* srcptr)
{
    *destptr = malloc(strlen(srcptr)+1);
    strcpy(*destptr, srcptr);
}
```

and call as:

```
foo(&nodeptr->word, word);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function

```
void foo(char* destptr, const char* srcptr)
{
    destptr = malloc(strlen(srcptr)+1);
    strcpy(destptr, srcptr);
}
```

the parameters `destptr` and `srcptr` are local to the function `foo`. They are automatic variable, i.e., have automatic storage allocation. This mean they are allocated on the stack when the function is called and are destroyed when the function returns. Calling `foo` as

```
foo(nodeptr->word, word);
```

simply copies the value of `nodeptr->word` to `destptr` and of `word` to `scrptr`. Therefore, the variables `nodeptr->word` and `word` are not changed. Allocating memory and assigning to `desptr` in `foo` function causes memory leak since that memory is not free and handle to it is lost when `foo` returns.

What you should do is pass the address of `nodeptr->word` to `foo` and change the signature of `foo` accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct HASH_NODE
{
    char *word;
    struct HASH_NODE *next;
} HASH_NODE;

void foo(char **destptr, const char* srcptr)
{
    *destptr = malloc(strlen(srcptr)+1);
    strcpy(*destptr, srcptr);
}

int main (void)
{
    HASH_NODE *nodeptr = malloc(sizeof *nodeptr);
    if(nodeptr == NULL) {
        printf("not enough memory to allocate\n");
        return 1;
    }
    nodeptr->next = NULL;
    nodeptr->word = NULL;
    const char *word = "cat";
    foo(&nodeptr->word, word);

    // after done with nodeptr
    free(nodeptr->next);
    free(nodeptr);
    //
    return 0;
}
```